# How to call Java's String constructor (char[], int offset, int length) from Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am migrating some Java code to Kotlin, and I have trouble migrating a call to Java's String constructor `(char[], int, int)` as it is not available in Kotlin.

Only `(char[])` constructor seem to be available. How do I overcome this?

**P.S.** I overcome this by writing: `(java.lang.String(buf, 0, i) as String)` and it seems that `java.lang.String` and `kotlin.String` are different. But it does not look so nice.

Comment: Not being a Kotlin developer, can your write your own method (in Java) which just calls the string constructor, and then call that from your Kotlin code?

Comment: @JonSkeet That is possible, but I wanted to have all codes in Kotlin (not mixed with Java).

Comment: In that case, can you just create a copy of the relevant "slice" of the array instead?

Comment: That is possible, but it has the consequences that array copy is done twice: once when making the slice, and once when creating the string. If possible I would like to prevent that, since this is called in a tight loop.

Comment: See answers below, you can call it directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the char array coming from java, for example

```
public class Test {
    public static char[] chars = {'a','b','c','d'};
}
```

And you want to use the constructor in the format `(char[], int, int)`

Then you could do it this way.

```
var a = Test.chars.slice(0..i).toString()
```

This will take your char array, slice it in the range 0 up until i, then get it as a string.

You could then just wrap that in a function and away you go

Answer (score 0):

You can just direct use the constructor.  This is valid in Kotlin:

```
val s = String(byteArrayOf(65,66,67,68,69), 0, 3)
```